# Error while trying to install jenkins.war file

Tags: java, jenkins

C:\WINDOWS\system32>java -jar C:\Users\Stark\Jenkins\jenkins.war

Running from: C:\Users\Stark\Jenkins\jenkins.war

webroot: $user.home/.jenkins

```
2021-07-01 12:18:00.228+0000 [id=1]     INFO    

org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log#initialized: Logging initialized @5448ms to 

org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog

2021-07-01 12:18:00.718+0000 [id=1]     INFO    winstone.Logger#logInternal: Beginning 
extraction from war file

2021-07-01 12:18:09.749+0000 [id=1]     INFO    winstone.Logger#logInternal: Jetty shutdown successfully

java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Stark\.jenkins\war\images\TangoProject-License.url (Access is denied)



        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at winstone.HostConfiguration.getWebRoot(HostConfiguration.java:299)
        at winstone.HostConfiguration.<init>(HostConfiguration.java:84)
        at winstone.HostGroup.initHost(HostGroup.java:66)
        at winstone.HostGroup.<init>(HostGroup.java:45)
        at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:174)
        at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:369)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at Main._main(Main.java:375)
        at Main.main(Main.java:151)
2021-07-01 12:18:09.798+0000 [id=1]     SEVERE  winstone.Logger#logInternal: Container startup failed

java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Stark\.jenkins\war\images\TangoProject-License.url (Access is denied)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at winstone.HostConfiguration.getWebRoot(HostConfiguration.java:299)
        at winstone.HostConfiguration.<init>(HostConfiguration.java:84)
        at winstone.HostGroup.initHost(HostGroup.java:66)
        at winstone.HostGroup.<init>(HostGroup.java:45)
        at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:174)
        at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:369)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at Main._main(Main.java:375)
        at Main.main(Main.java:151)
```

Comment: Did you tried running it as administrator?

Comment: What Jenkins version?